# TypeScript array object Filter - dynamic filter conditions, Search Refiners Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working on the below scenario in Typescript and SharePoint Search.

I have Collection of Array something like this:

```js
let _SelectedBusinessUnits =[
{ "fileName": "XYX.doc", "Region": "APAC", "Country":"Australia;China", "LOB": "Auto;Business Auto", SubLOB" : "Standard Auto" },
{ "fileName": "XYX2.doc", "Region": "UKIG", "Country":"UK;Germany", "LOB": "Wordings;Business Wordings", SubLOB" : "Super Wordings;YYY" },
{ "fileName": "XYX3.doc", "Region": "LTAM", "Country":"Japan", "LOB": "Endorsments;Business Endorsments", SubLOB" : "Super Endorsement" },
{ "fileName": "XYX4.doc", "Region": "APAC", "Country":"Australia:China", "LOB": "Auto;Business Auto", SubLOB" : "Standard Auto;XYHC" },
{ "fileName": "XY.doc", "Region": "UKIG", "Country":"UK, Germany", "LOB": "Wordings;Business Wordings", SubLOB" : "Super Wordings" },
{ "fileName": "XYX.pdf", "Region": "LTAM", "Country":"Japan", "LOB": "Endorsments;Business Endorsments", SubLOB" : "Super Endorsement" },
{ "fileName": "XYX.docx", "Region": "APAC", "Country":"Australia;China", "LOB": "Auto;Business Auto", SubLOB" : "Standard Auto" },
{ "fileName": "XYX.html", "Region": "UKIG", "Country":"UK;Germany", "LOB": "Wordings;Business Wordings", SubLOB" : "Super Wordings" },
{ "fileName": "X.pdf", "Region": "LTAM", "Country":"Japan", "LOB": "Endorsments;Business Endorsments", SubLOB" : "Super Endorsement" },]
```

I have filter conditions in another array of objects.

```js
let filercondition =[{
{"Region": "UKIG"},
{"Region": "APAC"}
{"LOB":'Wordings},
{"Country":'UK'}

 ]]
```

Now, I have scenario to filter the items based on the value I have in filter condition. [i.e I will select Region, Sublob or Lob etc.. I have respective multiselect dropdowns like Regions, country and lob and sublobs]

Based on the selection I do in the multiselect dropdowns I need to fetch. It is like refiner filters in search.

Comment: `.filter` is your friend. Learn more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @Nishant -- I have to filter with condition like Region='APAC' , Region = 'UKIG', LOB='Wordings', Country='UK'.. these are like multiple combination against one collection. I have the filter conditions in another array of object.let filercondition =[{
{"Region": "UKIG"},
{"Region": "APAC"}
{"LOB":'Wordings},
{"Country":'UK'}

 ]]

Comment: `filter` function takes the object of the the array and index. You can easily write your logic there `arr.filter(obj => {/* your logic to match multi value here */});`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#filter` with `array#some` to find the object based on filter condition. For each object in `businessUnits` look for matching words in your `filercondition` array.

```
businessUnits.filter(o => {
   return filtercondition.some(obj => Object.keys(obj).some(k => o[k] === obj[k]));
});
```

```js
let businessUnits = [{
      "fileName": "XYX.doc",
      "Region": "APAC",
      "Country": "Australia;China",
      "LOB": "Auto;Business Auto",
      "SubLOB": "Standard Auto"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "XYX2.doc",
      "Region": "UKIG",
      "Country": "UK;Germany",
      "LOB": "Wordings;Business Wordings",
      "SubLOB": "Super Wordings;YYY"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "XYX3.doc",
      "Region": "LTAM",
      "Country": "Japan",
      "LOB": "Endorsments;Business Endorsments",
      "SubLOB": "Super Endorsement"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "XYX4.doc",
      "Region": "APAC",
      "Country": "Australia:China",
      "LOB": "Auto;Business Auto",
      "SubLOB": "Standard Auto;XYHC"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "XY.doc",
      "Region": "UKIG",
      "Country": "UK, Germany",
      "LOB": "Wordings;Business Wordings",
      "SubLOB": "Super Wordings"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "XYX.pdf",
      "Region": "LTAM",
      "Country": "Japan",
      "LOB": "Endorsments;Business Endorsments",
      "SubLOB": "Super Endorsement"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "XYX.docx",
      "Region": "APAC",
      "Country": "Australia;China",
      "LOB": "Auto;Business Auto",
      "SubLOB": "Standard Auto"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "XYX.html",
      "Region": "UKIG",
      "Country": "UK;Germany",
      "LOB": "Wordings;Business Wordings",
      "SubLOB": "Super Wordings"
    },
    {
      "fileName": "X.pdf",
      "Region": "LTAM",
      "Country": "Japan",
      "LOB": "Endorsments;Business Endorsments",
      "SubLOB": "Super Endorsement"
    },
  ],
  filtercondition = [
    {
      "Region": "UKIG"
    },
    {
      "Region": "APAC"
    },
    {
      "LOB": "Wordings"
    },
    {
      "Country": "UK"
    },
  ],
  result = businessUnits.filter(o => {
    return filtercondition.some(obj => Object.keys(obj).some(k => o[k] === obj[k]));
  });

console.log(result);
```